# Version control using timestamp

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, transactions, h2

I have a database `DB` with table `T` (`id` int, `version` timestamp) and  application `APP` that works with this database and table. What I need to do:

1. Lock table `T`.
2. Select some rows from table `T`.
3. Get current time `curTimeStamp`.
4. Unlock table `T`.
5. All rows thar are updated after unlocking tables (#4) must have `version` > `curTimeStamp`. Their `version` is set in UPDATE statement using SQL functions, for example, `now()`, `current_timestamp()` etc. I mean `UPDATE T SET version=now()`;

After reading a lot of information I think about such solution:

1. Start SQL transaction with `read committed` isolation level.
2. Execute SELECT statement to get rows of table `T`
3. Execute SELECT to get `curTimeStamp`.
4. Commit SQL transcation.

However, some RDMS, for example [H2 and Posgtresql](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15167385/5057736) return same value of `now()` functions inside one transaction. And as I understand then if some update transaction started before my select transaction AND update transaction finished after select transaction then `row.version` will be < `curTimeStamp`.

I am not very good in SQL transactions and I have doubts about my solution. Is this solution correct? If not, please, show my mistakes and right direction.

Comment: In Postgres you can use `clock_timestamp()` instead. That will advance inside a transaction. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you for such useful information. But I need a solution for both Postgresql and H2. H2 seems doesn't support such feature http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34478259/current-moment-in-h2-database . So maybe it is better to implement version control on application level instead of database level? Or solution is in general correct?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34478259/current-moment-in-h2-database